# UIPageViewController in swift while Scrolling forward and backward, Index is not printing Correct

Tags: swift, uipageviewcontroller

Here I have programmed the UIPageViewController in Swift. It is working. But when I swipe/scroll the page forward or backward, the index is not printing correctly. The desired page is opening correctly. However, the value of index of this page is not printing correctly in the console. Also, sometimes it is not printing the index on scrolling, while the page is opening correctly. Please help me on how I can get correct index for the page while scrolling. The code is given below.....

```
var pageViewController: UIPageViewController!
let pages = ["TabOneVc","TwoVC","ThreeVc","FourVc"]

func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? 
{
    if let index = pages.indexOf(viewController.restorationIdentifier!){
        if index > 0{
               print(index)
               return viewcontrollerAtIndex(index - 1)
         }
      }

    return nil
}

func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? 
{
  if let index = pages.indexOf(viewController.restorationIdentifier!){

        if index < pages.count - 1{
                print(index)
                      return viewcontrollerAtIndex(index + 1)
            }
    }
    return nil
}

func viewcontrollerAtIndex(index: Int) -> UIViewController?
{
    let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(pages[index])
    print("index path",index)
    return vc
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(When you swipe through and land on a view controller it will also load the next view controller so it is ready and this will therefore call viewControllerAtIndex again and print the next index from the one you are currently on, causing the issue of the wrong index.)

The correct way to achieve the current index is to implement this delegate method:

`func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted completed: Bool){`

Check if `transitionCompleted` is true (for when a page has fully changed) and then use this to get the current index based off your current code:

`let viewController = pageViewController.viewControllers![0] as! ViewController
let index = pages.indexOf(viewController.restorationIdentifier!)`

This gets the first view controller in the pageViewController array and uses your current code to get its index from restortationIdentifier.

Hope this helps.